# How to Use Android Native code as Android Titanium Module for Square payment SDK

Tags: titanium, square, titanium-modules, titanium-sdk

I'm developing a mobile app using Titanium and need to integrate Square's Mobile or Web SDK to generate a payment token for card payments. I plan to send this token to my backend for processing payments. Could someone provide guidance or code examples on how to implement this Square SDK within a Titanium app? Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Square official documentation providing an way to integratae Square SDK for Native Adnroid and iOS but I want to implement for Titanium project by using their custom Module.

[following reference link for In-App Payments SDK on Android for Square](https://developer.squareup.com/docs/in-app-payments-sdk/build-on-android)

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.